# SAP BW Info Providers and SSIS

Tags: ssis, sap-bw

Is there a way to extract data directly from SAP BW Info Providers (Info Cubes, Multi Providers, Info Objects, Query's) using SSIS without having to use Open Hub or Infospokes.  Using SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

For InfoCubes and BEx queries, you will have to look into SSIS component set like AecorSoft Integration Service (disclaimer: our most popular product).

For InfoObjects and Data Store Objects, you can get the actual transparent table names (e.g. /BI0/0COMP_CODE_ATTR) and then extract data from those tables using AecorSoft component.